# Asp.Net-Core with Razor Pages Bind hidden input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my java script file I am setting the value of a hidden input like this:

```
document.getElementById("myVal").value = 11;
```

In my html:

```
<input asp-for="Value" id="myVal" />
```

In my Asp.Net-Core Web Application with Razor Pages I am trying to bind this property so I can take the value :

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
   [HiddenInput] //I also tried to add [BindProperty] after
   public int Value { get; set; }

   public void OnGet()
   {
       Debug.WriteLine(Value);
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
function redirect() {
    document.getElementById("myVal").value = 11;
}
```

This function is called when I click a button, and that is when the value is being set to 11.

What I want is that when this button is clicked, I can save the value myVal so that I can use it in my Razor Page.

The problem is that the value of the field will always be 0 (even when the field is not hidden). How can I set the value for the hidden field?

Comment: First of all, you need to understand that the `OnGet` method is a method that is executed when the page is just loaded. At this time, html has not been rendered, so you cannot get the value set to myVal in js in the `OnGet` method.
Or, you can trigger the post method by clicking the button like the following reply, and get the Value in the post method.
But we don't understand what you mean  `I need those values to be send automatically`?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

- i define post method

  ```
    [BindProperty]
    [HiddenInput] 
    //I also tried to add [BindProperty] after
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        int a = Value;
    }
  ```

*in page

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
<input asp-for="Value" id="myVal" />

<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

<script>
 document.getElementById("myVal").value = 11;
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution seems the right way but the problem is that I need those values to be send automatically, not when I press button send

Comment: What do you mean by send automatically? Do you want it to be an Ajax request on value changed?

Comment: you can submit form in jquery or js

Comment: this submit form     "document.getElementById("myForm").submit();"
but it repaet infintly

Comment: @vahab-balouchzahi You need to define some trigger then, e.g. something changed, onload & etc. Unless you have something like timer (that also works as trigger btw), but that would make a very little sense.